# Can IdentityServer return claims as part of authenticate request

Tags: owin, claims-based-identity, ws-federation, claims, thinktecture

I am implementing wsfed authentication using wsfederation plugin on top of Thinktecture IdentityServer, I got my own UserService implemented with AuthenticateLocalAsync method as below

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateLocalAsync(string username, string password, SignInMessage message)
        {
            var requestViewModel = new SignInRequestViewModel
                              {
                                  EmailAddress = username,
                                  Password = password
                              };

            var result = await signInApplicationService.SignInAsync(requestViewModel);

            var responseViewModel = result.ViewModel;

            var claims = claimBuilder.GetClaims(responseViewModel);

            return new AuthenticateResult(
                responseViewModel.CustomerId.ToString(),
                string.Format("{0} {1}", responseViewModel.FirstName, responseViewModel.LastName),
                claims);
        }
```

This method get called when a login event triggered, as you can see I authenticate users against my own database repository, then from the result I built up claims object which referenced in `AuthenticateResult` object and return back.

So I thought that the claims should now be available on the client, so no need to make further request, but it actually makes second request to itself which the `GetProfileDataAsync` method get called, and based on document:

> This method is called whenever claims about the user are requested
>   (e.g. during token creation or via the userinfo endpoint

Which kinda of making sense, but does it mean that I need to call my database again to retrieve customer data again, and rebuild the claims same as I did in my `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method?

If so, what's the point to pass claims back in the first authenticate method?

Can someone explain please?

Thanks

Ming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to GetProfileDataAsync has a ClaimsPrincipal. The claims you put there in the authentication stage should be on that principal. So no need for a db roundtrip.

If the claims are not to be found there, this would be a bug and you should open an issue on the issue tracker.